# Best Package for Sparse Matrix Multiplication

Tags: c++, python, matlab, sparse-matrix, matrix-multiplication

I am looking for the best package for sparse matrix multiplication on single core solution.
I am not looking for CUDA, MPI or OpenMP solutions.

My preference for languages in decreasing order : Matlab, Python, C/C++.

Matlab has its own matrix multiplication function which can be used for sparse matrix multiplication. But are there any better package(s) available ?

I have to multiply two large matrices which are in sparse format.

Eg., one matrix is 677000-by-48000 and another is 48000-by-8192. Here, n-by-d means n : # of rows, d : # of columns

Comment: That depends on the application.

Comment: core MATLAB, Python [Scipy](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/sparse.html), [Sparse BLAS](http://math.nist.gov/spblas/), [SparseLib++](http://math.nist.gov/sparselib++/), [SPARSKIT](http://www-users.cs.umn.edu/~saad/software/SPARSKIT/), [Eigen](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Main_Page), [uBLAS](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/numeric/ublas/doc/index.htm)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm no expert for sparse matrices but I do know the renowned ['eigen'](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org) C++ library.

They have a tutorial on sparse matrices, reachable from the [documentation page](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox).